# How to stop serving ad asset (remove link to asset) using google api

Tags: python, google-ads-api

I need to make inactive **assets** linked to a specific **ad**, i.e. to get the same result through the api as in the google ads web interface. Example by following the [link](https://imgbb.com/L8NC6QP)

I've tried it myself in two ways

1. I wanted to try and delete the asset itself, but I found a description in the documentation that the asset cannot be deleted using [AssetService](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/reference/rpc/v10/AssetService?hl=en) because it does not support a remove operation
2. Ok, I tried to remove an ad using AdGroupAdService using [sample](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/samples/remove-ad?hl=en) (using python but this is not crucial) but got an message about this operation not for an ad with type **APP_AD**
   message: "Cannot remove an adgroup ad with this ad type."

In the end, I found information that in order to stop an asset, the link between the asset and the ad has to be removed. But nowhere is there any example of what this is or how to do it. Any help with this problem would be greatly appreciated.